# Write variables in PLC from EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, plc

I have an ActiveX communication driver for TCP / IP that allows me to read and write to a PLC from an Excel file. I want to write the value 5 MW having another 5 cells in Excel, I tried it with loop and I wrote in the 5 variables at a time only one value. Now I have a "Select Case" it does not work me. Please help. The code is as follows:

```
For tt = 1 To 5
        valor(1) = Val(Cells(1, 4).Value)
        valor(2) = Val(Cells(2, 4).Value)
        valor(3) = Val(Cells(3, 4).Value)
        valor(4) = Val(Cells(4, 4).Value)
        valor(5) = Val(Cells(5, 4).Value)

    Next tt

    Select Case valor(tt)
        Case valor(1)
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 5, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
        Case valor(2)
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 6, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
        Case valor(3)
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 7, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
        Case valor(4)
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 8, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
        Case valor(5)
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 9, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
    End Select
```

The line:

```
MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 9, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
```

Are the parameters of communication with the PLC to Settings. The last parameter is the value we need to write, which I gather from a cell.

The code is VBA in Excel 2002.

THANKS!!!

Comment: the select case is outside the for/next loop. So when you reach the select case the value of tt will always be the same. And surprise surprise ... tt will always be 6 after finalization of the loop. So the select case will never find a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
For tt = 1 To 5
    valor(1) = Val(Cells(1, 4).Value)
    valor(2) = Val(Cells(2, 4).Value)
    valor(3) = Val(Cells(3, 4).Value)
    valor(4) = Val(Cells(4, 4).Value)
    valor(5) = Val(Cells(5, 4).Value)

    Select Case valor(tt)
    Case valor(1)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 5, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
    Case valor(2)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 6, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
    Case valor(3)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 7, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
    Case valor(4)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 8, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
    Case valor(5)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 9, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
    End Select
Next tt
```

Answer (score 0):

As cboden pointed out the select-statement is outside of the for-loop. Instead of implementing a select-statement you should do it like this (read the rest of this post for an explanation):

```
For tt = 1 To 5
    valor = Val(Cells(tt, 4).Value)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 4+tt, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
Next tt
```

---

Explanation:

Keep in mind that the for-loop will run all code inside the loop once for each value of tt (1,2,3,4,5), which means that this:

```
For tt = 1 To 5
    valor(1) = Val(Cells(1, 4).Value)
    valor(2) = Val(Cells(2, 4).Value)
    valor(3) = Val(Cells(3, 4).Value)
    valor(4) = Val(Cells(4, 4).Value)
    valor(5) = Val(Cells(5, 4).Value)
Next tt
```

Can (and *should*) be written like this:

```
For tt = 1 To 5
    valor(tt) = Val(Cells(tt, 4).Value)
Next tt
```

The select-statement is not only wrong but also unecessary. The correct version (if you choose to put it in the for-loop, which I do *not* recommend since it is redundant and makes the code harder to read) is:

```
Select Case tt
    Case 1
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 5, 1, 1000, 300, valor(1))
    Case 2
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 6, 1, 1000, 300, valor(2))
    Case 3
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 7, 1, 1000, 300, valor(3))
    Case 4
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 8, 1, 1000, 300, valor(4))
    Case 5
        res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 9, 1, 1000, 300, valor(5))
End Select
```

The above can be shortened to:

res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 4+tt, 1, 1000, 300, valor(tt))

for each value of tt (1,2,3,4,5) and if put into the for-loop together with `valor(tt) = Val(Cells(tt, 4).Value)` will form:

```
For tt = 1 To 5
    valor(tt) = Val(Cells(tt, 4).Value)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 4+tt, 1, 1000, 300, valor(tt))
Next tt
```

Since we do not need to keep the array of valor we can remove the `valor(tt)` and replace it with `valor`, thus making the finished code:

```
For tt = 1 To 5
    valor = Val(Cells(tt, 4).Value)
    res2 = MB1.Write("10.56.35.214", "10.56.35.22", 502, 0, 16, 4+tt, 1, 1000, 300, valor)
Next tt
```

---

Also I would suggest that you, in the future, refrain from posting IP-addresses in such a public forum.